# javamail and sendmail take ~17 minutes to send the first email

Tags: java, clojure, jakarta-mail, ring

My clojure and ring based application runs well on my Ubuntu 14.04 box.

The login system is "get an email link to click on," so firstly a user must input their email.

When I run the app using

```
java -jar app.jar
```

It starts a server and all is well, but it seems like interally javax.mail (and perhaps sendmail?) are taking a long time to resolve some hostnames or something.

I just tried running

```
sudo sendmailconfig
```

after install sendmail.

After about 17 minutes there is no delay and the emails come great, but until that point, the system just appears to "hang" while sending an e-mail.

Any advice is welcome.

Some code:

```
(ns pachax.handler
  (:require [postal.core :as mailmail]))

 (mailmail/send-message 
   {:host secrets/host, 
    :user secrets/user, 
    :pass secrets/pass
    :ssl true}
   {:from secrets/user, 
    :to username-input, 
    :subject "PracticalHuman Login Link Requested."
    :body body-message})
```

Which is nothing special, digging deeper into what postal is actually made of helps a bit:

https://github.com/drewr/postal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=smtp-send

```
(defn ^:dynamic smtp-send* [^Session session ^String proto
        (.sendMessage transport jmsg (.getAllRecipients jmsg)))
      {:code 0 :error :SUCCESS :message "messages sent"})))
```

which uses transport.sendMessage (i think)

Some relevant source code seems to be in the sendmail.clj
https://github.com/drewr/postal/blob/4b445ef606f1bdeab832a7179595a41832be3edb/src/postal/sendmail.clj

```
 (def sendmails ["/usr/lib/sendmail"
                 "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
                 "/usr/bin/sendmail"
                 "/usr/local/lib/sendmail"
                 "/usr/local/sbin/sendmail"
                 "/usr/local/bin/sendmail"
                 "/usr/sbin/msmtp"])
```

so I'm uncertain which sendmail program is being invoked, and how javax.mail is involved.

```
Extra info:
   1) visit website, enter your e-mail
   2) sends you an email and then displays a message saying you got a link
   3) you click the link and you are in.
```

System "hangs" on step 2, where the initial batch of e-mails will just have the site "loading" a POST result which is really just the "hey you got a link" message.

After about 17 minutes all the emails show up in my inbox, and there-after the requests for new links are processed very quickly.

Comment: It does sound like a name service configuration problem.  Does it hang if you try to send email to the domain of the sending machine?  Are you able to resolve host names for the email addresses you're sending to?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @BillShannon, but that is a little over my head.  Currently I'm just using gmail to send messages and it works great.  The server itself is not configured as a mail server.  Eventually, the mails do come (all at once) and from then the behavior is copacetic.  So to answer your questions: email to the domain -> not set up.  Host names resolve?  yes, but I don't know to what or where I'd find out.

Comment: Are you using JavaMail to send directly using Gmail?  Or are you using JavaMail to send through one of your local machines (using sendmail?) and from there to a Gmail address?  How exactly are you measuring the 17 minutes?  Is it the time between two statements in your program?  Is it the time from Transport.send to when you actually receive the message?

Comment: @sova can update the question with the snippet of code you're using to send email? Obviously redact your credentials, if any.

Comment: @DiegoBasch yes, thanks for the suggestion.  It made me look into the postal sourcecode on github, and although I do not know the issue focal point yet, I feel like we are making progress.

Comment: Try to put some logging code around the invocation of `send-message`. I don't know the libraries, but if the invocation of the local `sendmail` command works, it should return pretty directly. `sendmail` is typically an alias for a local MTA, it could be exim or something else. Mail can be delayed before it's send out, depending on your MTA config -- which would be off-topic for SO. If you can track it down to your local MTA, you might want to ask on Serverfault or Superuser SE.

Comment: What/where are the addresses you are sending mail to? This does sound like a DNS lookup delay. Are all the messages your trying to send in the same domain or different domains? Is it a 'real' domain or are you doing some sort of dynamic domain name setup to have the messages sent back to you? Is the from address you are sending the mail as the same as your gmail address?

Comment: Yes the "from" adress is the same.  If you look at the code above you can see both refrence secrets/user (which is an actual file named secrets with a var "user")  ... It seems like javax.mail has some sort of glitch in figuring it out, but it only happens on my ubuntu Server, not on my actual dev machine.